# How do I convert .pdf files to .chm? on a Mac?

Tags: file-conversion

How do I convert .pdf files to .chm? on a Mac?

Comment: CHM is just a container for HTML files.  What you need is a CHM decompiler and an HTML->PDF converter, since I think you're unlikely to find them bundled.  Unfortunately I don't use Apple software so I can't advise on specific apps.

Comment: @Shinrai, actually I think the OP needs the opposite of what you're saying.  He needs a PDF->HTML which can then be made into CHM.

Comment: Errr you're exactly right.  I'm not sure how I did that, haha.  The point stands though, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I want pdf to chm conversion.

Comment: So you need to convert PDF->HTML and then find a CHM packager.  It seems to me this isn't as straightforward though unless your PDF has embedded links or something (you can do this with PDF right? I don't use it much). Hopefully somebody will come suggest good OS X compatible apps.